# Angular Form Submit

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms, form-control

In my departments.component.html, I have this:

> Focus on the `#form` and calling of `addDepartment(form.formValues)`

```html
<app-dialog-form *ngIf="showDialogBox" [(showDialogBox)]="showDialogBox" #form [values]="department">
    Register Department
    <div class="action" action>
        <button class="ui button basic" (click)="onToggleDialogBox()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="ui button primary medium" (click)="addDepartment(form.formValues)">Save</button>
    </div>
</app-dialog-form>
```

The getting of values in my formValues is this:

```js
get formValues(): any {
  let data;
  data = this.dialogForm.value;
  return data;

}
```

And here is my code for addDepartment()

```js
addDepartment(department: Department) {
    console.log(department.name);
    if (typeof department === 'object') {
        this.departmentService
        .registerDepartment(department)
        .subscribe(
            res => { alert(res); 
                    //this.goBackToDepartmentListPage(); 
                   },
            error => alert(error)
        )
    }
}
```

But everytime, I submit the form values and try printing in the console the input, I get this error

```
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at 
DialogFormComponent.get [as formValues]
```

Comment: Can you show how `this.dialogForm` is being initialized. That property is what is undefined. I suspect that could be a life cycle hook problem.

Comment: How do you initialize it? I just declared it `dialogForm : FormGroup`

Comment: There are only 2 fields. Name and Remarks. But in the database, there are other properties. So do you initialize only the one the user needs to input in the form?

Comment: You have to use the FormBuilder to create a FormGroup object. Did you do that step?

Comment: Now I did in ngOnInit() `this.dialogForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      remark: ['', Validators.maxLength(1000)]
    }) ` but it says Validation failed

Comment: Move your `formBuilder.group` to the constructor. That way `this.dialogForm` is assigned a value before the template checks it. Only use `ngOnInit` when you need to read from `@Input` bindings.

Comment: What do you mean by transferring it to constructor? I already placed `private formBuilder: FormBuilder` in constructor. Should I just add another method?